# Can any JavaScript library perform as well as the Cut The Rope JavaScript implementation?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Now that the canvas tag is starting to get hardware execration [acceleration - thanks guys!] by many browsers, developing casual games in HTML5 is becoming more feasible. ZeptoLabs did a great job porting Cut The Rope to HTML5 for use as a Windows 8 Metro App. You can find some of the details [here](http://www.cuttherope.ie/dev/) but they do not get into specifics. I was wondering if anyone knew if they used a library (such as [Impact](http://impactjs.com/) or [Crafty](http://craftyjs.com/)) or if you need to write all custom and optimized JavaScript code in order to get this type of performance.

Thanks!

Comment: I learned a new word today. Execration. Thanks.

Comment: [Execration](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/execration) seems to be an existing word. I think that you meant "acceleration", though ;)

Comment: I'm using crafty for a mmo atm (no previews available :\), which works suprisingly well, even in fullscreen but only, if most of the image is static, like in the game you linked. With HW-acceleration it works even smoother, the only framerate drops, I discoverd, came from some buggy background activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is strictly a StackOverflow question (it's informational, rather than looking for a solution to a programming problem), but it would seem that, since [`libraries.js`](http://www.cuttherope.ie/scripts/libraries.js) contains a number of libraries but none are really "game" libraries (e.g., SoundManager2, jQuery, etc.), they did most of the heavy lifting themselves.

As for whether those game frameworks you mentioned will offer the high performance you're looking for, well, only one way to find out.